# how can i change the the ndk version in adroid react native project on mac os m1?

Tags: android, react-native, android-ndk

In my local enviroment with mac os 13.1 (22C65) chip m1 i have a react native 0.63.4 with gradle 6.1.1.1 and ndk instaled 21.4.7075529 by the android studio

build.gradle file:

```
 buildscript {
 ext {
 buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
 minSdkVersion = 24
 compileSdkVersion = 31
 targetSdkVersion = 31
 ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
 reactNativeFFmpegPackage = "full-gpl" //add this line
 }}
```

BUUUUUTTTT when i try to run on terminal with the cli `$ ./gradlew assembleRelease` in android project i have the FAILURE:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols'.
>
> > No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.0.6113669. Versions available locally: 21.4.7075529

when i change the ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529" to "21.0.6113669 and remove the folder ndk in ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/ it works, But how can i change the the ndk version on this local environment to work?

Comment: I founded my problem, i have two build.gradle in my app and one in app folder and another in android folder i set the ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529" in the another file and this run!

Answer (score 1):

You need to open android studio and then go to SDK Manager, after that click on SDK Tools, and you can find NDK over here. then click on show package details so you can check all the available versions of NDK. You can refer attached image for the same.

You can select it as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dyana,my problem was set the ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529" in wrong place, your answers is good its works to install a new ndk version on mac.